# Oracle - truncating time from a timestamp field

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-format

I'm looking to get a count of email click rates by day however I cannot figure out the starting structure of the query. Can someone please help? I'm learning SQL and this website has been a great resource for me. Thank you!

```
SELECT TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP, DATE) as DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM EMAILCLICK
GROUP BY DATE
```

Example of EVENTTIMESTAMP = `02-JAN-20 02.32.50.462000000 PM`

Comment: You need to `group by` the `trunc()` expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are multiple issues in that query, not just `group by`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues in your query:

1. Wrong syntax for `TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP, DATE)`
2. Missing `TRUNC` in `GROUP BY` clause. You cannot use alias name in group by clause, you must mention the same expression used in the `SELECT`.
3. `DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle.

You need to use correct syntax:

```
SELECT TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP) as "DATE", COUNT(*)
FROM EMAILCLICK
GROUP BY TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP);
```

> as DATE

Remember, `DATE` is a **reserved keyword in Oracle**. You should either use a proper alias name or use it as **quoted identifier** by enclosing within double-quotation marks `"`.

Comment: That's right, thanks for fixed, I just wrote pseudocode but had not yet tested

Comment: This worked with the DATE in quotes. Ahh, thank you so much for your help to you and everyone!!!! I will save this and update my notes for this one.

Comment: Just a side observation - since DATE is a reserved word, it's poor practice to try and get around it with tricks like quoting "DATE".  Just use a better alias.  The word 'date' is rather generic anyway. Why not add an adjective -- 'select trunc(eventtimestamp) as EVENT_DATE'.  That avoids the reserved word issue entirely _and_ gives you a more descriptive header in your result set/report.

Answer (score 0):

Hope will help you.

```
select TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP) as "DATE", COUNT(*)
from EMAILCLICK
GROUP BY TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: It will still fail, as `DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle. It will throw `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: select TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP) as "DATE", COUNT(*)
from EMAILCLICK
GROUP BY TRUNC(EVENTTIMESTAMP)